# DataNodes can't talk to NameNode

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

Set up a Hadoop cluster of 3 nodes. One of them got both NameNode and DataNode roles while other two are just DataNodes.

I started all nodes and services but in summary it shows only one of DataNodes's status is live. Status of other nodes are not even showing.

[image]

My question is what is the difference between being started and being live? And why other nodes don't have a status at all?

I guess the issue is datanodes can't talk to namenode. So as [Azwaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215825/datanodes-are-not-live-dead-or-decommissioning-ambari/30222008#comment48588399_30222008) pointed out, I checked /etc/hosts file. It was like this:

```
127.0.0.1   nnode.domain nnode localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.1.4.212 nnode.domain nnode
192.1.5.124 dnode02.domain dnode02
192.1.5.125 dnode01.domain dnode01
```

I changed first line to:

`127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4`

Now I can establish connection with nnode.domain:50070, however errors at datanode side changed. Here log piece from datanode:

```
2015-05-15 10:08:21,721 ERROR datanode.DataNode (DataXceiver.java:run(253)) - dnode01.domain:50010:DataXceiver error processing unknown operation  src: /127.0.0.1:49000 dst: /127.0.0.1:50010
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:315)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.readOp(Receiver.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:212)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-05-15 10:08:23,670 INFO  datanode.DataNode (BPServiceActor.java:register(782)) - Block pool BP-2116866246-127.0.0.1-1431441630609 (Datanode Uuid null) service to nnode.domain/192.1.4.212:8020 beginning handshake with NN
2015-05-15 10:08:23,674 ERROR datanode.DataNode (BPServiceActor.java:run(840)) - Initialization failed for Block pool BP-2116866246-127.0.0.1-1431441630609 (Datanode Uuid null) service to nnode.domain/192.1.4.212:8020 Datanode denied communication with namenode because hostname cannot be resolved (ip=192.1.4.1, hostname=192.1.4.1): DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0, datanodeUuid=7f1be518-1255-4a6a-b31c-22be5dc47673, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=8010, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-51d1dfd0-9376-44a7-b581-c14eec95fd74;nsid=450599258;c=0)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.registerDatanode(DatanodeManager.java:887)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.registerDatanode(FSNamesystem.java:5282)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.registerDatanode(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1082)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.registerDatanode(DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:92)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.DatanodeProtocolProtos$DatanodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(DatanodeProtocolProtos.java:26378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)
```

This is odd, there is no host with 192.1.4.1 IP address. Why would datanodes try to connect 192.1.4.1?

```
Unresolved datanode registration: hostname cannot be resolved (ip=192.1.4.1, hostname=192.1.4.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving NameNode to same network with DataNodes solved the problem.

DataNodes are in 192.1.5.* network.

NameNode was in 192.1.4.* network.

After moving NameNode to 192.1.5.* did the trick for my case.

Answer (score 2):

"Datanodes 3/3 started" means 3 datanodes process running

Datanodes status "1 live / 0 Dead / 0 Decommissioning" means your namenode is able to communicate with one node.

It seems to be a network problem (make sure [HDFS ports](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/) are open on your firewall). The alive Datanode is probably on same machine as your Namenode.

Comment: Actually, I already turned off iptables on all nodes. So there is no firewall between nodes.

Comment: Can you post log of datanodes and namenode ? On namenode screen, do you see all datanodes ? (web interface on port 50070 of your namenode)

Comment: This log is from one of the datanodes:


 `2015-05-14 17:20:52,273 INFO  ipc.Client (Client.java:handleConnectionFailure(859)) - Retrying connect to server: nnode.domain/192.1.4.212:8020. Already tried 25 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)`


I can't establish connection with namenode on port 50070. It also looks like same thing applies for port 8020 too. I wonder what causes this..

Comment: Do you use /etc/hosts file ? Entries in this file are correct ?